# Execute Access 2007 Report and Export that Report to PDF Programmatically?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have a great report in an Access 2007 Database and would like to automate the execution and exportation of that report.  Is this possible and what would be your first guess at the method needed to pull it off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to automate using the DoCmd.OutputTo method.  I think the PDF feature requires SP1 for A2007.  Here's a simple example:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport,"rptFoo",acFormatPDF,"D:\Access\rptFoo.pdf"
```

Look at the MSDN page for more details: [DoCmd.OutputTo Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238050%28office.12%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238050(office.12).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336132(office.12).aspx