# VBA Create PDF in background

Tags: ms-access, pdf-generation, vba

I'm maintaining a VBA application in Access and a big part of this program is to make PDF's and email. I've already coded to create a PDF with PDF995, but the problem is that it keeps prompting where to save and a bunch of other questions.
Is there any solution that allows me to create PDF's in the background without prompting the user anything? I know where it needs to be saved, I know how it's going to be named, so that's not the problem.

Comment: have you tried reading the manual?

Comment: I spent a lot of time trying to get it to work with this commercial tool, but I want to see if there's maybe an 'embedded' way in VBA to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Which Access version are you using?
In Access 2007 and above you can create PDF files out of the box, without stuff like prompting where to save.
Here's an example:
[Execute Access 2007 Report and Export that Report to PDF Programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602864/execute-access-2007-report-and-export-that-report-to-pdf-programmatically)
Note that in Access 2007, you have to [install an add-in](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9943) in order for this to work!

For Access 2003 and below, there's [Steven Lebans' ReportToPDF](http://www.lebans.com/reporttopdf.htm).